# How to click and upload multiple images in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, multipartform-data, multipart, dio

I want the user to click multiple images using the device's camera which will show in the app with some details filled by the user, after that, I want to send all of the data to a server as formdata with an array of images. how can I modify the following code to do so

```
// file for clicking 1st image
File image;

// setting the 1st fiile if picked
Future getFile() async {
  var imagePicker = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (ImagePicker != null) {
    setState(() {
      image = imagePicker;
    });
  }
}

// funtion to upload the selected image
_uploadFile() async {
  try {
    // sending request with other fields
    String fileName = image.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      'action': 'add_intimation',
      // want to send array or multiple images in this field
      'chessisPhoto[]': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        image.path,
        filename: fileName,
      ),
    });
    // mapping data and sending post requesst
    Response response = await dio.post(
      'https://irsindia.org/apis.php',
      data: formData,
    );
    // printing the respos
    print("File upload response: $response");
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List of Multipartfile . Please refer to [this](https://fluttertutorial.in/multiple-image-upload-using-multipart-in-flutter/)

Comment: hello thank you for responding can you tell me how to handle the image picking option? currently, I have a single button that clicks the image from the device's camera can I use the same button to click multiple images and then display them?

Comment: You can use [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) or [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) on same button users will be able to select either one or multiple no problem there. Both allows to select multiple file/image/media.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below example code where user can pick maximum 5 images

Using these packages

images_picker: ^1.2.4

flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0

[image]

[image]

```
class PickMultipleImagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PickMultipleImagesScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PickMultipleImagesScreenState createState() =>
      _PickMultipleImagesScreenState();
}

class _PickMultipleImagesScreenState extends State<PickMultipleImagesScreen> {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> attachMultipleImages = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  List compressedPhotosList = ["place_holder"];
  int maxImagesCount = 5;

  pickPhotos() async {
    List<Media> photosList = [];
    photosList = await ImagesPicker.pick(
      count: (compressedPhotosList != null &&
              (compressedPhotosList.isNotEmpty) &&
              (compressedPhotosList.length > 1))
          ? (maxImagesCount + 1 - compressedPhotosList.length)
          : maxImagesCount,
      pickType: PickType.all,
      language: Language.System,
      cropOpt: CropOption(
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(600, 400),
      ),
    );

    if (photosList != null && photosList.isNotEmpty && photosList.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < photosList.length; i++) {
        File photoCompressedFile =
            await compressImage(File(photosList[i].path));
        print("Images List: $photosList");
        print("Path of UnCompressed File: ${photosList[i].path}");
        compressedPhotosList.insert(
          0,
          photoCompressedFile.path.toString(),
        );
        print("Path of Compressed File: ${photoCompressedFile.path}");
        print("Compressed Images List: $compressedPhotosList");
      }
      attachMultipleImages.value = !attachMultipleImages.value;
    }
  }

  Future<File> compressImage(File file) async {
    final filePath = file.absolute.path;
    final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.png|.jp'));
    final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    if (lastIndex == filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.png'))) {
      final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          filePath, outPath,
          minWidth: 1000,
          minHeight: 1000,
          quality: 50,
          format: CompressFormat.png);
      return compressedImage;
    } else {
      final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        filePath,
        outPath,
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 1000,
        quality: 50,
      );
      return compressedImage;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: attachMultipleImages,
        builder: (context, snapshot, child) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: (compressedPhotosList != null &&
                    compressedPhotosList.isNotEmpty &&
                    compressedPhotosList.length > 1)
                ? GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: (compressedPhotosList != null &&
                            compressedPhotosList.isNotEmpty &&
                            compressedPhotosList.length > 1 &&
                            (compressedPhotosList.length - 1 == maxImagesCount))
                        ? compressedPhotosList.length - 1
                        : compressedPhotosList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ((compressedPhotosList[index] == "place_holder") &&
                              compressedPhotosList.length - 1 != maxImagesCount)
                          ? InkWell(
                              onTap: () async {
                                if (compressedPhotosList.length - 1 !=
                                    maxImagesCount) {
                                  pickPhotos();
                                }
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                                  5.0,
                                ),
                                width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(105.0),
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    size: ScreenUtil().setSp(24.0),
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Stack(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                  child: Image.file(
                                    File(compressedPhotosList[index]),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                    width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(105.0),
                                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                                    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                      return Container(
                                        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(105.0),
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Positioned(
                                  bottom: 10,
                                  right: 8,
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      compressedPhotosList.removeAt(index);
                                      attachMultipleImages.value =
                                          !attachMultipleImages.value;
                                    },
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 15.0,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.delete_forever,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                    },
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        pickPhotos();
                      },
                      child: Text("Attach Images"),
                    ),
                  ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```